# issue with laser reading in robot turn 90 degree right using ROS

Tags: python, ros, robotics

Task 2

Inside the python_exam folder, create a new Python script, named task2.py, that does the
following:

a) First, it starts moving the robot forwards while it captures the laser readings in
front of the robot.

b) When the laser readings detect that there's an obstacle (the wall) at less than 1
meter in front of the robot, the robot will stop its movement.

c) After it stops, the robot will turn 90 degrees to his right, facing the opening
corner in the room

**Here is My Code :**

```py
from robot_control_class import RobotControl
import time

current_time = time.time()

# Create an instance of the RobotControl class
robotcontrol = RobotControl()


# initially get a laser scan
a = robotcontrol.get_laser(360)
# use a conditional while loop
while (a >= 1.1):  # change here: stop just less than 1m in front of the wall

    # move robot
    robotcontrol.move_straight()
    print("Current distance to wall: %f" % a)
    # wait delay for 1.0 seconds to move straight
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # update laser scan reading for while loop
    a = robotcontrol.get_laser(360)

# once while loop exits, stop the robot
robotcontrol.stop_robot()

# Update measurement after the robot stops
a = robotcontrol.get_laser(360)
print("Current distance after Stop: %f" % a)

# Turn the robot 90 degrees to the right
robotcontrol.turn(90, -1, 1.7)
time.sleep(5)
print("measurement after turn 90 should be inf ..")
print("testing .....")

# Update measurement after the robot turns
a = robotcontrol.get_laser(360)
print("measurement after turn 90: %f" % a)

# Concatenate a string and an integer
clockwise = "clockwise"
t = 5
print("Turned robot {} for {} seconds".format(clockwise, t))
```

**My Output resulting This :**

```
Current distance to wall: 5.515752
Current distance to wall: 5.039326
Current distance to wall: 4.567775
Current distance to wall: 4.036658
Current distance to wall: 3.503789
Current distance to wall: 2.954841
Current distance to wall: 2.495076
Current distance to wall: 1.974109
Current distance to wall: 1.437561
Current distance after Stop: 0.841572
measurement after turn 90 should be inf ..
testing .....
measurement after turn 90: inf
Turned robot clockwise for 5 seconds
```

The issue is :

> front laser value is not correct
>
> left laser value is not correct

Here is the Test video showing everything works well except when grading the task show me the errors above with gradebot :
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-Ks_93oHDg&ab_channel=NasserCzar](https://youtu.be/g-Ks_93oHDg)

Comment: please if you need more info let me  know without disliking , thnx

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to invoking [this method](https://github.com/arnaldojr/Python-3-for-Robotics/blob/master/robot_control_class.py):

> ```
>     def turn(self, clockwise, speed, time):
> ```

But your call was:

> ```
>         robotcontrol.turn(90, -1, 1.7)
> ```

Rather than denoting degrees,
that `90` seems to function as
more of a comment than anything else.
The called method was expecting that it
might have a directional value like `"clockwise"`.

---

It would be worthwhile to `print()` the diagnostic
result that comes back from `.turn()`.
Also, while you're debugging turning,
it would be useful to query the current
compass heading and report that.

Comment: forgive my ignorance , when i add the forth parameter it show me an error TypeError: turn() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given) , so that's why I let it 3 parameter

Comment: @NasserCzar The first value param of `turn` is expected to be a `str`. So its not expecting a euler angle rotation, but instead how long it should rotate. For example: `robotcontro.turn("clockwise", 1, 1.7)` turns clockwise for 1.7 seconds at a speed of 1. If the first param is anything else it will do the same speed/rotation, but counterclockwise.